# Atlassian Jira On Demand Migration to TFS 2012

Tags: tfs, migration, jira, tfs-migration

Are there any tools available for migrating from **Jira on Demand** to TFS 2012 ? All the tools that I saw needs Jira to be installed locally on our servers.

Comment: Which tools have you seen?

Comment: And there is no way to add a URL for the Jira Instace?

Comment: Boris, can you please elaborate your question?

Comment: how about import and export using excel?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. I would start creating a custom importer by using the JIRA REST API to extract the data from JIRA. I'm not sure what import methods there are for TFS though

Answer (score 0):

I'd think the easiest way would be to write a quick'n'dirty script to scrape everything out using the on-demand instance's REST API.

It should be enabled by default on all on-demand instances ( unless explicitly turned off. )

The API is documented at:

http://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/